# How to create an own Google Oauth Scope (writeonly)?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

My goal is to have a Google (Drive) Oauth Scope which gives the permissions of **writeonly**. I can't find it in the [google drive oauth scopes list](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes).

So is it possible to create a own scope? -Or is there another solution?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: further to the correct answer below, the "other solution" is to write your own proxy app that front-ends Drive. You'd need to explain more detail about your architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create a scope that is not already documented. In your case there is only readOnly or readWrite.
if it applies to your case, you may use the individial file-level drive scope which only gives access to specific individual files including newly created files by your app.
Note that write-only doesnt make much sense as a permission since editing the file would require to have access to the original content, unless its append-only (not supported) or create-only (file scope has this)

Comment: +1. drive.file scope gives you permission to write new files and read/modify those same files. The only extra permission this scope gives you @Kybi is the ability to read files a user has explicitly opened with the App.

Comment: Right, write-only makes not a lot of sense, actually I wanted a create-only. I hope Google will create it soon. In the meantime I will (try to) use the drive.file scope.